# Expanding a symbolic multivariate polynomial with R for usage in POV-Ray

Tags: r, symbolic-math, polynomials, povray

Consider the following trivariate polynomial with two parameters `a` and `b`:

```
P(x,y,z) = ((x*x+y*y+1)*(a*x*x+b*y*y)+z*z*(b*x*x+a*y*y)-2*(a-b)*x*y*z-a*b*(x*x+y*y))^2-4*(x*x+y*y)*(a*x*x+b*y*y-x*y*z*(a-b))^2
```

In POV-Ray, I want to plot the algebraic isosurface of equation `P(x,y,z)=0` for some values of `a` and `b`. In POV-Ray, one has to define the polynomial by listing its monomials where each monomial is given as follows:

```
xyz(i,j,k): coef
```

where `i,j,k` are the exponents and `coef` is the coefficient of `x^i y^j z^k`.

For example one has the monomials `b^2 y^8 = b^2 x^0 y^8 z^0` and `2*b*a x^6 z^2 = 2*b*a x^6 y^0 z^2` and then they must be given as follows:

```
xyz(0, 8, 0): pow(b,2),
xyz(6, 0, 2): 2*b*a,
......
```

It is not funny to manually expand the given polynomial. I want to generate this POV-Ray code with R.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with the packages **Ryacas** and **partitions**.

First, let's enter the polynomial in **Ryacas**:

```r
library(Ryacas)
expr <- "((x*x+y*y+1)*(a*x*x+b*y*y)+z*z*(b*x*x+a*y*y)-2*(a-b)*x*y*z-a*b*(x*x+y*y))^2-4*(x*x+y*y)*(a*x*x+b*y*y-x*y*z*(a-b))^2"
yac_assign(expr, "POLY")
```

Let's see the degree of each variable:

```r
yac_str("Degree(POLY, x)") # 8
yac_str("Degree(POLY, y)") # 8
yac_str("Degree(POLY, z)") # 4
```

So we need the exponents `i,j,k` with possible values for `i` and `j` between `0` and `8` and possible values for `k` between `0` and `4`. We use the **partitions** package to generate the *compositions* of these three integers. For example, the compositions summing to `4` are obtained by:

```r
library(partitions)
compositions(4, 3)
                                  
[1,] 4 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0
[2,] 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0
[3,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

Here is a function which takes a composition `(i,j,k)` and returns the coefficient of `x^i y^j z^k` prepended by `xyz(i,j,k):`:

```r
f <- function(comp) {
  if(comp[3L] > 4L) return(NULL)
  xyz <- sprintf("xyz(%s): ", toString(comp))
  coef <- yac_str(sprintf(
    "ExpandBrackets(Coef(Coef(Coef(POLY, x, %d), y, %d), z, %d))",
    comp[1L], comp[2L], comp[3L]
  ))
  if(coef == "0") return(NULL)
  # replace a^p with pow(a,p) for POV-Ray, same for b^p:
  coef <- gsub("([ab])\\^(\\d+)", "pow(\\1,\\2)", x = coef)
  paste0(xyz, coef, ",")
}
```

Then we loop over the degree:

```r
for(deg in 0L:8L){
  comps <- compositions(deg, 3L)
  povray <- apply(comps, 2L, f, simplify = FALSE)
  cat(
    unlist(povray), sep = "\n", file = "polynomial.pov", append = deg > 0L
  )
}
```

We obtain the desired code in the file **polynomial.pov**:

```
xyz(4, 0, 0): pow(a,2)*pow(b,2)-2*pow(a,2)*b+pow(a,2),
xyz(2, 2, 0): 2*pow(b,2)*pow(a,2)-2*pow(b,2)*a+(-2)*b*pow(a,2)+2*b*a,
xyz(0, 4, 0): pow(b,2)*pow(a,2)-2*pow(b,2)*a+pow(b,2),
xyz(3, 1, 1): 4*pow(a,2)*b-4*pow(a,2)+(-4)*a*pow(b,2)+4*a*b,
xyz(1, 3, 1): 4*pow(a,2)*b+(-4)*a*pow(b,2)-4*a*b+4*pow(b,2),
xyz(6, 0, 0): (-2)*pow(a,2)*b-2*pow(a,2),
xyz(4, 2, 0): (-2)*pow(b,2)*a+(-4)*b*pow(a,2)-4*b*a-2*pow(a,2),
xyz(2, 4, 0): (-4)*pow(b,2)*a-2*pow(b,2)+(-2)*b*pow(a,2)-4*b*a,
xyz(0, 6, 0): (-2)*pow(b,2)*a-2*pow(b,2),
xyz(4, 0, 2): (-2)*a*pow(b,2)+2*a*b,
xyz(2, 2, 2): (-2)*pow(b,2)*a+6*pow(b,2)+(-2)*b*pow(a,2)-8*b*a+6*pow(a,2),
xyz(0, 4, 2): (-2)*b*pow(a,2)+2*b*a,
xyz(5, 1, 1): 4*pow(a,2)-4*a*b,
xyz(3, 3, 1): 4*pow(a,2)-4*pow(b,2),
xyz(1, 5, 1): 4*a*b-4*pow(b,2),
xyz(3, 1, 3): 4*pow(b,2)-4*b*a,
xyz(1, 3, 3): (-4)*pow(a,2)+4*a*b,
xyz(8, 0, 0): pow(a,2),
xyz(6, 2, 0): 2*pow(a,2)+2*a*b,
xyz(4, 4, 0): pow(b,2)+4*b*a+pow(a,2),
xyz(2, 6, 0): 2*pow(b,2)+2*b*a,
xyz(0, 8, 0): pow(b,2),
xyz(6, 0, 2): 2*b*a,
xyz(4, 2, 2): (-2)*pow(a,2)+10*a*b-2*pow(b,2),
xyz(2, 4, 2): (-2)*pow(a,2)+10*a*b-2*pow(b,2),
xyz(0, 6, 2): 2*a*b,
xyz(4, 0, 4): pow(b,2),
xyz(2, 2, 4): 2*a*b,
xyz(0, 4, 4): pow(a,2)
```

Comment: Heh, looks fantastic :). If you don't mind to add the rendered image, please? I was using POVray about 25 years ago, and now I feel great nostalgia for it :).

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko the image is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72316222/1100107

Comment: And for those of us stumbling to render the above in `povray`, either here or at Saturn, if you could point to a properly formed `that_annoying_line_artifact.pov`, that uses the output of this fascinating `Ryacas`, `partition`,  `spray`, `povray` pipeline.

Comment: @Chris It's probably on my [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@stla3716/videos) with a link to the code.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but perhaps, transitioning from version, camera, lights to action, are the above  ex. `xyz(0,0,2): 2*b*a`  evaluated to `xyz(0, 6, 2):  0.045000000000000005,` by povray when wrapped in `polynomial {8 ...`when presented in their polynomial form? The link above seems to suggest that evaluated values are in the `.pov` rather than the polynomial (29) strings. Strictly, none of my question here addresses finding which polynomial is leaving y and(x,z -though to lesser extent) unbounded to the mobius extent/skin, but being able to 'look' at it might help.,

Comment: @Chris It seems this is an antialisaing issue. When I change the antialiasing method (there are three methods), this is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the **spray** package.

```r
library(spray)

x <- lone(1, 5)
y <- lone(2, 5)
z <- lone(3, 5)
a <- lone(4, 5)
b <- lone(5, 5)

P <- ((x*x+y*y+1)*(a*x*x+b*y*y)+z*z*(b*x*x+a*y*y)-2*(a-b)*x*y*z-a*b*(x*x+y*y))^2-4*(x*x+y*y)*(a*x*x+b*y*y-x*y*z*(a-b))^2


nterms <- nrow(P[["index"]])

coeffs <- P[["value"]]

XYZpowers <- P[["index"]][, c(1L, 2L, 3L)]
XYZ <- apply(XYZpowers, 1L, function(comp) {
  sprintf("xyz(%s): ", toString(comp))
})

ABpowers  <- P[["index"]][, c(4L, 5L)]

a <- lone(1, 2)
b <- lone(2, 2)
abPolys <- lapply(1L:nterms, function(i) {
  pows <- ABpowers[i, ]
  coef <- coeffs[i]
  coef * a^pows[1L] * b^pows[2L]
})

AB <- split(abPolys, XYZ)

ABgroups <- sapply(AB, function(poly) {
  Reduce(`+`, poly)
}, simplify = FALSE)

ABgroups <- Filter(Negate(is.empty), ABgroups)


asCharacter <- function(poly) {
  op <- options(sprayvars = letters)
  x <- capture.output(print_spray_polyform(poly))
  options(op)
  x
}

ABchar <- sapply(ABgroups, asCharacter, simplify = FALSE)

asPOVRay <- function(poly) {
  gsub("([ab])\\^(\\d+)", "pow(\\1,\\2)", x = poly)
}

ABpov <- sapply(ABchar, asPOVRay)

paste0(names(ABpov), unlist(ABpov))

#  [1] "xyz(0, 4, 0): +pow(b,2) +pow(a,2)*pow(b,2) -2*a*pow(b,2)"                
#  [2] "xyz(0, 4, 2): -2*pow(a,2)*b +2*a*b"                                      
#  [3] "xyz(0, 4, 4): +pow(a,2)"                                                 
#  [4] "xyz(0, 6, 0): -2*a*pow(b,2) -2*pow(b,2)"                                 
#  [5] "xyz(0, 6, 2): +2*a*b"                                                    
#  [6] "xyz(0, 8, 0): +pow(b,2)"                                                 
#  [7] "xyz(1, 3, 1): -4*a*b +4*pow(a,2)*b +4*pow(b,2) -4*a*pow(b,2)"            
#  [8] "xyz(1, 3, 3): +4*a*b -4*pow(a,2)"                                        
#  [9] "xyz(1, 5, 1): -4*pow(b,2) +4*a*b"                                        
# [10] "xyz(2, 2, 0): +2*a*b -2*pow(a,2)*b +2*pow(a,2)*pow(b,2) -2*a*pow(b,2)"   
# [11] "xyz(2, 2, 2): -2*a*pow(b,2) +6*pow(b,2) -2*pow(a,2)*b -8*a*b +6*pow(a,2)"
# [12] "xyz(2, 2, 4): +2*a*b"                                                    
# [13] "xyz(2, 4, 0): -4*a*b -2*pow(a,2)*b -4*a*pow(b,2) -2*pow(b,2)"            
# [14] "xyz(2, 4, 2): -2*pow(a,2) -2*pow(b,2) +10*a*b"                           
# [15] "xyz(2, 6, 0): +2*pow(b,2) +2*a*b"                                        
# [16] "xyz(3, 1, 1): +4*pow(a,2)*b +4*a*b -4*pow(a,2) -4*a*pow(b,2)"            
# [17] "xyz(3, 1, 3): +4*pow(b,2) -4*a*b"                                        
# [18] "xyz(3, 3, 1): +4*pow(a,2) -4*pow(b,2)"                                   
# [19] "xyz(4, 0, 0): -2*pow(a,2)*b +pow(a,2) +pow(a,2)*pow(b,2)"                
# [20] "xyz(4, 0, 2): -2*a*pow(b,2) +2*a*b"                                      
# [21] "xyz(4, 0, 4): +pow(b,2)"                                                 
# [22] "xyz(4, 2, 0): -4*a*b -4*pow(a,2)*b -2*pow(a,2) -2*a*pow(b,2)"            
# [23] "xyz(4, 2, 2): +10*a*b -2*pow(b,2) -2*pow(a,2)"                           
# [24] "xyz(4, 4, 0): +pow(b,2) +4*a*b +pow(a,2)"                                
# [25] "xyz(5, 1, 1): +4*pow(a,2) -4*a*b"                                        
# [26] "xyz(6, 0, 0): -2*pow(a,2) -2*pow(a,2)*b"                                 
# [27] "xyz(6, 0, 2): +2*a*b"                                                    
# [28] "xyz(6, 2, 0): +2*pow(a,2) +2*a*b"                                        
# [29] "xyz(8, 0, 0): +pow(a,2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are indeed instances of the spray and partitions packages being used as intended.  I do very much like the method of looping over the degree from 0-8 and then using `compositions()`, although it is possible to streamline this very slightly:

```r
suppressMessages(library("partitions"))
summary(blockparts(rep(8,3),8,TRUE))
#>                                                 
#> [1,] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 ... 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
#> [2,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ... 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 0
#> [3,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It is somewhat mortifying to me that I can't easily reproduce Stéphane's wonderful solution with `mvp`.  Here I would observe that the applications above are a rare case where the symbolic nature of the `mvp` package is counterproductive, and the somewhat more rigid structure of `spray` is actually helpful.  We see that x,y,z and a,b are confined to their own columns, and Stéphane exploited this immutability of the spray package.

Comment: I think you mean `blockparts(c(8, 8, 4))`, since the degree of `z` is 4.